# how to unhighlight select element after option is chosed?

Tags: javascript, html

lets say i have a `select` element in my html and an `eventListener` in javascript that `console.log`s some text when i press the <kbd>space</kbd> key

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", myFunc);

function myFunc(event){
      if (event.code === 'Space') {
        console.log("hi");
      }
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="">test</option>
  <option value="">test</option>
  <option value="">test</option>
</select>
```

When i click on one of the options, the `select` element automatically closes but its still highlighted. So if i press the space key, it opens the `select` element instead of executing the `console.log` function

I have to click outside the `select` element after i choose an option so i can `console.log` some text when i press the <kbd>space</kbd> key

Is there a way so that i don't have to click outside the `select` element every time i want to press the key?

Comment: Try `keydown` event

Comment: @User863 but i want to fire the function when user releases key so i need to use `keyup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `blur()` function on select element at `change` event listener.

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", myFunc);
const selectEle = document.getElementById("select");

function myFunc(event){
      if (event.code === 'Space') {
        console.log("hi");
      }
}

selectEle.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  selectEle.blur();
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="">test</option>
  <option value="">test</option>
  <option value="">test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what does `blur()` do?

Comment: removes focus on the element.

Comment: it sets focus out of select element, so that on pressing space key it doesn't open dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

Just blur it programatically on change, `this.blur()`:

```html
<select id="select" onchange="this.blur()">
  <option value="">test</option>
  <option value="">test</option>
  <option value="">test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @RahulKumar it is supported form the beginning of time, i.e version 1 of major browsers, deprecating and removing such things are going to break the internet. Maybe you wanted to leave a comment about "best practices", which is completely out of scope of this example imo.

Comment: @RahulKumar you can see that MDN itself uses it in the documentation of `blur` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur

Comment: sorry, i mean to say best practice and felxibility.. recommended

Answer (score 2):

## HTMLElement.blur()

The **HTMLElement.blur()** method removes keyboard focus from the current element.

Syntax:

**element.blur();** // negates focus on an element

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur